# How to query firebase in readonly mode

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have some data in firebase that I want to query. My firebase has default security settings which is readonly. However when I try to query the data as below

```
this.firestore.collection('myCollection').valueChanges().pipe().subscribe(x => {
  console.log;
});

this.firestore.collection('myCollection').get().subscribe(x => {
  console.log;
});
```

I do get an error `Missing or insufficient permissions.` As per my understating that should not be the case as I am just reading the data. Also I probably have to mention that I am using `@angular/fire`

> Just for an experiment I did try to enable the write access to
>   database and it works this way but I want to keep the readonly mode.

that is my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your security rules?

Comment: If you have correctly enabled read access for myCollection in your security rules, your code should work.  So, something is wrong with your rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson just added the rules, as I said it is just a default which is seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

you are not allowing readonly access, since it is equivalent to

```
....
allow read: if false;   // <- You deny any read here
allow write: if false;
....
```

---

You need to adapt your rules as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

---

More info in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), including the video at the top of the doc.

Comment: oh, ok I didn't think of that this way.